# Domain checking failed when e2e tests executed in the Gitlab CI

Tags: firebase, gitlab, gitlab-ci, cypress, e2e-testing

I try to test some code relying on Firebase with Cypress. But this tool checks the domain of requests. How can I know the domain used by the requests when executed within the gitlab ci?

I'm launching e2e tests this way:

```
"ci:start-server": "angular-http-server --path ./dist/treo -p 4200",
"cy:run": "cypress run --project e2e --browser chrome --headless",
"ci:cy-run": "start-server-and-test ci:start-server http://localhost:4200 cy:run"
```

Notice that tests are successful when executed locally since the `localhost` domain was added in the Firebase console.

Thanks for your help,
Thierry

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. How is a webserver running on `localhost` on your computer any different than running on `localhost` in GitLab CI? It's just another computer, after all. If you ran the tests on _my_ computer, would you expect the tests to pass or fail? Do you have some sort of IP whitelist?

Comment: Thanjs bery much for your comment! Yes yes agreed but Firebase does a domain checking. Adding localhost is enough for local testing but doesn't work for the gitlab ci...